# find -or not printing all results

Tags: linux, find, gnu

Directory containing these files:

```
irrelevant  irrelevant.doc  dok1.txt  dok2.text  dok3.txt  dok4.text
```

I need to find all *txt and *text files and do some transformations on them.

`find` command and result:

```
$ find -name '*txt' -or -name '*text'
./dok2.text
./dok4.text
./dok3.txt
./dok1.txt
```

This is ideally the result I need, to pass these four files to `-exec`.

Unfortunately `find` with `-print` (or `-exec echo {} +`) produces:

```
$ find -name '*txt' -or -name '*text' -print
./dok2.text
./dok4.text
```

Apparently it's this case of find (from find man page):

```
NON-BUGS
   Operator precedence surprises
       The command find . -name afile -o -name bfile -print will never print afile
       because this is actually equivalent to find . -name afile -o \( -name bfile
       -a -print \).  Remember that the precedence of -a is higher than that of -o
       and when there is no operator specified between tests, -a is assumed.
```

How should the find command be given to have all four files available to -exec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the or-ed expressions so that they, as a group, have the same precedence as and-ed expressions that follow:

```
find \( -name '*txt' -or -name '*text' \) -print
```